# Ubuntu Server 12.04 RAID 5 with Samba

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 off a flash drive. I am trying to create a file server baised off of SAMBA. I have 3 1Tb drives attached to the server. How to I set up the RAID and route data to be stored their and not on the flash drive. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For building the raid array you'll need to use `mdadm` command. It's a nightmare to use so expect to get things wrong and have to restart several times. You can clear mdadm configuration from a drive by clearing the superblock on the drive (you'll find it somewhere in the commands). Every time I use it I seem to have to start at the beginning trying to work it out -- it's certainly not intuitive (I always think of it as "mad admin" because if it doesn't make you mad at least once you're probably doing it wrong).

Once you have the array set up you'll need to use `parted` (normal partition) or `pvcreate`, `vgcreate` then `lvcreate` (LVM) to set it up. After you have that done you can create a file system on it by using the `mkfs` command. You should probably go for `ext4`.

Finally, to use it you'll need to create a folder where you want it to appear and then use the `mount` command to make it available. Somewhere inside the `/mnt/` structure is probably a good place to first think about doing this.

Finally, if you want to have it auto-mount when the machine starts then look at the `fstab` file.

There's a lot of commands here, too many to give detailed answers for, but hopefully this will get you started in the right direction and you can specific questions about the steps if you find you get into trouble.

Test everything before you start to put any real data on the disks -- especially test and get familiar with what happens when one of the disks disappears. You'll need to be able to work out which disk has gone just from the descriptions that `mdadm` gives you. `cat /proc/mdstat` is your friend here, `watch cat /proc/mdstat` is even more useful (especially to monitor the recovery).